# Crash / Freeze / Unresponsive - Ubuntu 20.04 - ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 8

Tags: 20.04, freeze, crash

After running for several hours at seemingly random times my laptop freezes, the screen is stuck and is unresponsive to any input from mouse or keyboard.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with Regolith 1.6, some help diagnosing the problem would be really appreciated, the crash was at **16:27:05**. Things I have tried:

- run LENOVO BIOS hardware checks for all components including CPU, MEMTEST, FAN, MOTHERBOARD, and all tests passed.
- Updated to latest firmware for Lenovo with `sudo fwupdmgr get-updates` and `sudo fwupdmgr install N2WET34W.cab`
- checked `ls -l /var/crash`, and there are no crash logs
- checked `/var/log/syslog`, there were no errors, and the last log message was two minutes before the crash happened, does not seem relevant:

```
Mar  1 16:25:01 x1 CRON[362611]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

- checked `/var/log/kern.log`, the last message was about 45 minutes before the system came unresponsive.

```
Mar  1 15:43:14 x1 kernel: [ 9675.073687] perf: interrupt took too long (3170 > 3133), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63000
```

- I have reinstalled the system from scratch, same OS Ubuntu 20.04 and desktop environment Regolith 1.6, in the hope this would stop the issue, but still the system becomes unresponsive after some hours of use.

It seems odd that this does not happen under any particular load, it seems to happen after some hours of uptime, and all hardware checks passed.

I am running out of ideas here to get to the bottom of this, some help would be really appreciated. Thank you

Also my RAM usage is not exccessive i.e.:

```
>>> free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.4Gi       1.9Gi       2.6Gi       464Mi       2.9Gi       4.8Gi
Swap:           9Gi          0B         9Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved with `5.13.0-30-generic` and Ubuntu 21.10 via `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Seemed to be a kernel bug with i7 intel processors and kenerls older than 5.4:

See: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051

Comment: Assessing that the issue occurs with i7 and kernel before 5.4 might be wrong.

I do have this issue with i5 and kernel 5.4.0

Comment: I have this issue with i5 and kernel 5.19.0-35-generic